# How do I call a dictionary value from another class in c#?

Tags: c#, class

I created a form in C#.  I want to display the value of a meter when a button is clicked.  How can I reference a dictionary term from another class?

```
using System;

public class Dictionary
{
    public void References()
    {
        Dictionary<string, double> Length = new Dictionary<string, double>(Lengths);

        Length.Add("Feet", 1);
        Length.Add("Meters", 0.3048);
    }
}
```

This function is in another class

```
    private void Done_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Meter_Feet = Dictionary.Length("Meters");

        MessageBox.Show("Meter_Feet");
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Your dictionary in the first class is a local variable. Local variables are not exposed for public consumption.

Comment: You can't, your `Dictionary` is a variable declared inside of a method and only belongs to the scope of that method.

Comment: Make your Dictionary Class either static with a static method which returns the dictionary, or make the dictionary a public property of class dictionary and create an object of type class Dictionary and use its public dictionary property.

Comment: I wouldn't create a class called `Dictionary`.  Name it something else.  Giving it the same name as a class from the BCL is generally frowned upon.

Comment: You should reconsider your design. Why are you creating a new class called `Dictionary`? That will just be confusing to your clients. Also, how would they know they need to call the `References()` method to initialize the internal dictionary? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: NEVER EVER name a class the same as an internal type

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("Meter_Feet");` is not the same as `MessageBox.Show(Meter_Feet);`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to create classes that are named identically to commonly used `System` classes (like `Dictionary`). It will create confusion, and will also often force users to use a fully qualified name to reference the one they want.

If you want to make a class member accessible to other classes, then you should declare it (or a property accessor for it) as a `public` member of your class. Also, instead of requiring a separate method to be called to populate the dictionary, you can put that code in the constructor so it gets called automatically, for example:

```
public class ConverterDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> Units { get; }

    public ConverterDictionary()
    {
        Units = new Dictionary<string, double>
        {
            {"Feet", 1},
            {"Meters", .3048}
        };
    }
}
```

Then the client just has to initialize your class to get the dictionary:

```
double Meter_Feet = new ConverterDictionary().Units["Meters"];
```

---

However, it looks like you're trying to create some kind of conversion class, in which case you might want to consider a different design. For example, you could create a static class that has methods for the types of conversions you want to do. The nice thing about a static class is that the client doesn't have to instantiate it - they can just call the methods. This works well for a conversion class, since the conversion rates are static (they don't ever change).

For example:

```
public static class ConvertUnits
{
    private const double MetersPerFoot = .3048;
    private const double FeetPerMeter = 3.281;

    public static double FromFeetToMeters(double feet)
    {
        return feet * MetersPerFoot;
    }

    public static double FromMetersToFeet(double meters)
    {
        return meters * FeetPerMeter;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    double feet;

    // Get input from user in a loop to ensure they enter a valid double
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number of feet to convert to meters: ");
    } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out feet));

    // Now we can use our converter class without any instantiation needed
    double result = ConvertUnits.FromFeetToMeters(feet);

    Console.WriteLine($"\nThere are {result} meters in {feet} feet.");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public property in your first class:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> Length {get;}
    public void References()
    {
        Length = new Dictionary<string, double>(Lengths);

        Length.Add("Feet", 1);
        Length.Add("Meters", 0.3048);
    }
}
```

Then you can refer to it as such:

```
    private void Done_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary();

        dictionary.References();
        double Meter_Feet = dictionary.Length["Meters"];

        MessageBox.Show(Meter_Feet);
    }
```